# MySQL database restore function in Qt

Tags: mysql, qt

I want to do a restore function for MySQL database by using QProcess in Qt C++, any idea please ?

NOTE: I use this code below to do backup

```
QProcess dumpProcess;
QStringList args;
args << "--user=root" << "--password=mysql" << "--host=localhost"<<"test";
dumpProcess.setStandardOutputFile("c:\\backup\\test11.sql");
dumpProcess.start("mysqldump", args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to restore a database is

mysql --user=user_name --password=user_password --host=host_name --port=port_number< backup.sql

I haven't tested but the code would be something like:

```
QProcess dumpProcess;
QStringList args;
args << "--user=root" << "--password=mysql" << "--host=localhost";
dumpProcess.setStandardInputFile("c:\\backup\\test11.sql");
dumpProcess.start("mysql", args);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Orcun,
But I tried before, and I did try it just now, but, unforetunately, it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried restoring your database from mysql prompt before using qt ? Does that work ?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it works perfectly with no problems at all! 
I droped a table,changed in other tables fields, but after restoring, everything is back to what it was

Comment: So what error are you getting with QProcess ? Have you checked QProcess::error () return value ?

Comment: It returned 5, Unknown Error! :(

Comment: Ok! It Solved now, Instead of C:\\ use C://
Thanks man for your help :)